# WPF Change DataGridCheckBoxColumn to Red Dots

Tags: checkbox, styles, wpfdatagrid

I want to change my checkboxes to red dots, in a datagrid's DataGridCheckBoxColumn. So checked items are red dots, while unchecked items are empty. How can I change the style inside DataGridCheckBoxColumn?

Comment: Your question, to me, looks a lot like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1345961/wpf-datagridcheckboxcolumn-custom-style?rq=1 That question has an accepted answer posted by Anvaka.

Comment: As a side note, if you provide us with information as to what you have already looked up and tried to solve your problem as well as posting some code we are usually able to assist you better.

Answer (score 0):

Try this out, it is adapted from [stackoverflow.com/questions/1345961/](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1345961/wpf-datagridcheckboxcolumn-custom-style?rq=1) that was mentioned by [Ansel Faillace](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4811494/ansel-faillace) in an earlier comment.

```
<DataGrid x:Name="dataGrid" Margin="10" ItemsSource="{Binding}">
    <DataGrid.Resources>
        <Style x:Key="GreenRedCheckBox" TargetType="{x:Type Checkbox}">
            <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Center />
            <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Top" />
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ToggleButton}">
                        <Border x:Name="innerBorder">
                            <Ellipse x:Name="statusLight"
                                     Fill="Red"
                                     Stretch="Fill"
                                     Stroke="Black"
                                     HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                                     VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                     Height="10"
                                     Width="10" />
                        </Border>
                        <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="True">
                            <Setter Property="Fill" TargetName="statusLight" Value="Green" />
                        </Trigger>
                        <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="False">
                            <Setter Property="Fill" TargetName="statusLight" Value="Red" />
                        </Trigger>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </DataGrid.Resources>
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGrideCheckBoxColumn ElementStyle="{StaticResource GreenRedCheckBox}"
                                 EditingElementStyle="{StaticResource GreenRedCheckBox}" />
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```